# How to get current modified record in custom entity listener in envers

Tags: hibernate-envers

I created a Listener CustomRevisionEntityListener which implements RevisionListener and CustomRevisionEntity(added column allocateTo) which extends DefaultRevisionEntity.

I annotated a class Employee with @Audited. Employee class has a field isAvailable.

My requirement is if user changes Employee -> isAvailable value to true, i need to update allocated column in CustomRevisionEntity record.

How to get modified employee model / employee_aud record in CustomRevisionEntityListener ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extended hibernate 'post-update' event, so that we can fetch dirtyProperties of entity 'Employee' and add the properties along with old and new values to CustomRevisionEntity.

Comment: hey murthy, i am facing same issue. could you please share code where you extended post-update event

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the "entity tracking revision listener". This allows you to be notified when an entity is changed. See here: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch15.html#envers-tracking-modified-entities-revchanges